# Generating a single year range in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I just wanted to generate a one year range using pandas
a range from 1/1 to 31/12 with no years, how can I do that?

Comment: With which frequency? If you need days, how would you handle leap years/February?

Comment: a frequency of one day, I already removed 29 February from all of the records

Comment: Did you try `pandas.date_range`?

Comment: @timgeb it requires a year for the start and end dates

Comment: well yes, timestamps have a year, what datatype is your result supposed to have?

Comment: @timgeb I have this dataset with different records each day from 2004 to 2015 and I'm supposed to visualize the min and max record for each day of the year from these records, so i thought maybe there's a way I can make range of 12 months to start with
I'm kinda new to this tho so if there's a better way I'm all ears

Comment: A better way would be not to try to generate a range by yourself and to rather use date-aware pandas capabilities to group/aggregate

Comment: how to compare the same day over different years tho?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example of the data (just a few dates for a few years) and the matching expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the 29th of February, just use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) on a non-leap year (like 2022):

```
pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', freq='d').strftime('%m-%d')
```

output:

```
Index(['01-01', '01-02', '01-03', '01-04', '01-05', '01-06', '01-07', '01-08',
       '01-09', '01-10',
       ...
       '12-22', '12-23', '12-24', '12-25', '12-26', '12-27', '12-28', '12-29',
       '12-30', '12-31'],
      dtype='object', length=365)
```

If you want a list add `.to_list()`.